# Wordpress Filezilla to AWS Permission Issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, permissions, filezilla

I'm trying to edit a wordpress .php file through Filezilla. I've connected correctly to the AWS instance with an ubuntu username. The problem is, I can view and make changes to the .php file but when I try to save those changes or re-upload them I get a permission denied error. I can add the file to the /ubuntu folder but no the /home folder where the wordpress files are located. That's as far as I can get at the moment, I know the permissions have to be changed, but i'm not sure how. Just trying to help out a non-computer savvy friend. Any help will be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file and go to `file permissions` and give the permission
for file 644
for folder 755

Answer (score 0):

To change file permission on ubuntu use `sudo chmod {options} filename`
[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Make sure that while creating any file or editing the file use `sudo vi filename`